# Show ECSlidingViewController on top of the TopViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I have my projet running smooth but I don't want my project to anchor on top right side. Is there a way to make the `ECSlidingViewController` show on top of its `topViewController`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this a while back. I won't say that it is not possible (you could always fork the repo and implement it :), but I decided to go with https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to stick, as much as possible, to `ECSlidingViewController` if it allows me to show it on top of the other view. If it can't, I'll just try to go for your solution with `KYDrawerController`

Comment: Whenever you reach a decision, I am very interested in hearing what you decided.